# How to keep an application running until the user exits the app?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I keep Android App alive in background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9541991/can-i-keep-android-app-alive-in-background)

I am developing an voip application which should run continuously, however the android OS is killing the application after 30 minutes approx. Kindly suggest any solution to keep the application alive until the user exits the application.

Comment: What do You mean by 'application'? Is it paused activity or background service?

Answer (score 0):

How does the user "exit" the application? Exiting goes against Android design. Android will kill the app when it's not being used anymore. If you need your app to stick around until the user explicitly force closes the app, use a [Service](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html). If you start the service using the `Context.startService()`, the service will stick around after your activity is destroyed. The service will only be stopped if Android is running dangerously low on resources (unlikely to happen).

Comment: yes correct i now created a service and then load all the stack in the service so that even if the activity is destroyed the app would force close... thanks for your reply

Comment: sorry the app won't force close...

Comment: there is a problem again... I changed the initialization of my stack and brocastreceiver to Service, however after sometimes the service run once again so it again initialize the stack. How can i overcome this?

Comment: onCreate should only be called once if you initially start the service with startService(). If you just bind to the service, it won't stick around. Also be sure to return START_STICKY from onStartCommand(). If you're having problems with double initialization, that can be overcome by a boolean instance variable.

Comment: i can use a boolean to overcome this issue however if i am on call in my app the call gets disconnected and the service starts once again and then reinitialize the sipstack and then register me again to sipserver which i dont want that to happen. So in short the service is called after apprx 30 minutes?? wondering why this is happening