# Location update from a repetitive task not working when mobile screen goes off

Tags: android, location

I have made a location update foreground service which gets locations directly(requestLocationUpdates) when interval is less than 30 secs and if its more than 30 sec, I use ScheduledExecutorService to get the location result and pool location results to get the best location. Only issue I am facing is I am not getting location updates when screen goes off. This code is working well till mobile screen goes off.

Please take care its a foreground service.

My Code is as below:

```
private boolean currentlyProcessingLocation = false;
public static int intervalForLocationRequestMethod = 500;
public static int intervalForLocationUpdates = 30000;
public int locationUpdateMethodThreshold = 5000;
public int sameLocationCounter = 0;
boolean locationUpdateMethodChanged = false;

ScheduledExecutorService sch;
Runnable periodicTask = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "run: repeat ");
        Intent i = new Intent(LocationService.this, LocationService.class);
        i.setAction(Constants.ACTION.STARTLOCATIONREPEAT_ACTION);
        startService(i);
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.i(TAG, "onCreate: ");

        buildGoogleApiClient();

    if (intervalForLocationUpdates <= locationUpdateMethodThreshold) {
        intervalForLocationRequestMethod = intervalForLocationUpdates;
    }
showOnGoingLocationServiceNotification();
}



private void showOnGoingLocationServiceNotification() {
    Log.i(TAG, "showOnGoingLocationServiceNotification: ");
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(MapsActivity.class);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("Forcee")
            .setTicker("Forcee Tracking")
            .setColor(Color.GREEN)
            .setContentText("Forcee is tracking your location....Tap to stop")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.cast_ic_notification_small_icon)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
            .setOngoing(true).build();
    startForeground(Constants.NOTIFICATION_ID.FOREGROUND_SERVICE, notification);}




@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(intervalForLocationRequestMethod);
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(intervalForLocationRequestMethod);

    if (intervalForLocationUpdates <= locationUpdateMethodThreshold || locationUpdateMethodChanged) {
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(50);
    }

    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
  LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand: ");

        Thread thread = new Thread(new LocationUpdateThread(intent, startId));
        thread.start();
        return START_STICKY;

}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Log.i(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);

    if (lastLocation != null) {
        if (location.distanceTo(lastLocation) >= 40.0f && locationUpdateMethodChanged && location.getAccuracy() <= 100.0f) {
            locationUpdateMethodChanged = false;
            currentlyProcessingLocation = false;
            sch = (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
            sch.scheduleAtFixedRate(periodicTask, intervalForLocationUpdates, intervalForLocationUpdates, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        }
    }

    if (location.getAccuracy() <= 100.0f) {
        if (firstLocationUpdateCall) {
            updatingLocation(location);
            firstLocationUpdateCall = false;
        } else {
            if (location.distanceTo(lastLocation) >= 40.0f) {
                updatingLocation(location);
                sameLocationCounter = 0;
            } else {
                if (intervalForLocationUpdates > locationUpdateMethodThreshold && !locationUpdateMethodChanged) {
                    sameLocationCounter++;
                    lastLocation = location;
                    Log.i(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + sameLocationCounter);
                    if (sameLocationCounter == 5) {
                        locationUpdateMethodChanged = true;
                        intervalForLocationRequestMethod = 1000;
                        stopLocationUpdates();
                        sameLocationCounter = 0;
                        sch.shutdownNow();
                        sch = null;
                        Intent i = new Intent(LocationService.this, LocationService.class);
                        i.setAction(Constants.ACTION.STARTLOCATIONREPEAT_ACTION);
                        startService(i);
                    }
                    Log.i(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + locationUpdateMethodChanged);
                }
            }

            if (intervalForLocationUpdates> locationUpdateMethodThreshold && !locationUpdateMethodChanged) {
                stopLocationUpdates();
                Log.i(TAG, "onLocationChanged: stopcheckshift");
            }
        }
    }
}

public void updatingLocation(Location location) {
    lastLocation = location;
    Log.i(TAG, "onLocationChanged: First " + locationPoints.size());
    locationPoints.add(location);
    Log.i(TAG, "onLocationChanged: Last " + locationPoints.size());
    sendLocationsToActivity(locationPoints);
    if (intervalForLocationUpdates > locationUpdateMethodThreshold) {
        stopLocationUpdates();
    }
}

public void sendLocationsToActivity(ArrayList<Location> locationPoints) {
    Log.i(TAG, "sendLocationsToActivity: ");
    Intent intent = new Intent("LocationUpdates");
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("Locations", locationPoints);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
}

private void stopLocationUpdates() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, LocationService.this);
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        currentlyProcessingLocation = false;
    }
}

final class LocationUpdateThread implements Runnable {

    int service_id;
    Intent intent;

    LocationUpdateThread(Intent intent, int service_id) {
        this.intent = intent;
        this.service_id = service_id;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.i(TAG, "run: ");

        if (intent != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "run: " + intent.getAction());
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.STARTFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
                toastHandler("Tracking Started!");
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                currentlyProcessingLocation = true;
                if (intervalForLocationUpdates > locationUpdateMethodThreshold) {
                    sch = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
                    sch.scheduleAtFixedRate(periodicTask, intervalForLocationUpdates, intervalForLocationUpdates, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                }
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.STARTLOCATIONREPEAT_ACTION)) {
                if (!currentlyProcessingLocation) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "run: curt");
                    checkLocationSettings();
                    currentlyProcessingLocation = true;
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.STOPFOREGROUND_ACTION)) {
                if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, LocationService.this);
                    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
                }
                if (sch != null) {
                    sch.shutdownNow();
                }
                stopForeground(true);
                stopSelf();
                toastHandler("Tracking Stopped!");
            }
        }
    }

    void toastHandler(final String msg) {
        Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        h.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(LocationService.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: sounds like doze mode has taken over. You have to take care of it, see here:https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html

Comment: Does foreground services also get affected by Doze?

Comment: Nothing in your code makes that a foreground service - you'd have to call `startForeground` for it to be a foreground service.

Comment: Its a foreground service. I have not shown that code here so as not to make readers overwhelmed by lengthy code.

Comment: Edited code and shown foreground service code.

Comment: yes it´s possible that doze mode does also effect foreground service. As mentioned on that link It should not affect it, but it depends **1. which android version you got** and **2.which device you got** .  On some earlier versions of MM, it was a bug that the doze mode does affect some things that it shouldn´t. If it is not a bug, just think about that there are some task managers/battery saver apps etc. that could kill you app. Huawei devices have their own battery management BESIDES the doze mode. So in that case, you have to deal with both.

Comment: See here for bugs: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?can=2&q=doze+mode&colspec=ID+Status+Priority+Owner+Summary+Stars+Reporter+Opened&cells=tiles

Comment: and see what I mentioned here for huawei devices: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29799187/android-background-services-and-alarms/29799795#29799795

Comment: thanks, i will keep these issues while updating my app.

Comment: Opiatefuchs I read about Doze and its affects on Foreground service. I learnt that i need to keep foreground service in a separate process to save it from being stopped by doze. But do I need to acquire partial wake lock for the length of service life as well to stop service being killed by doze or foreground service automatically acquire wakelock when it runs in separate process.